# SequelizeConnectionError: Bad handshake

Tags: mysql, node.js, sequelize.js

I am currently receiving a *SequelizeConnectionError: Bad handshake* error, on the 5th request that queries my MySQL database. Consistently fails on the 5th request that I am doing to the server.

I am using nodejs. The code that is handling the post request is as follows:

```
routes.post('/login', (req, res) => {
    var email = req.body.email,
        password = req.body.password;

    models.User.findOne({ where: {email : email} }).then(function(user) {
        if(user){
            user.validPassword(password).then(result => {
                if(result){
                    res.json({ "result": "Password correct"});
                } else {
                    res.json({ "result": "Password incorrect"});
                }               
            });
        } else {
            res.json({ "result": "User not found."});
        }
    });
});
```

The user.validPassword is as follows:

```
User.prototype.validPassword = function(password){
        var self = this;

        return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
            cryptPassword(password, function(err, encrypted) {
                resolve(self.password === encrypted);
            });
        });
    }
```

And the config for my Sequelize is as follows:

```
var sequelize = new Sequelize(config.database, config.username, config.password, {
  host: config.host,
  dialect: config.dialect,
  pool: {
    max: 100,
    min: 0,
    idle: 10000,
    handleDisconnects: true
  }
});
```

I have tried removing the pools, increasing the amounts, checked that there is not connection limit on MySQL, made sure certificates aren't required and re-installed my MySQL server.

The MySQL server is running on an Ubuntu 14.04 VPS, not hosted with Azure as some of the previous questions have been based off of.

Comment: What is sequelize version you are using?

Comment: I am using 4.28.6

Comment: And is your server really MySQL? May be mariadb? What dialect do you use for sequalize?

Comment: It is MySQL, quite sure about that. The dialect is mysql, (dialect: 'mysql')

Comment: Do you use `mysql` or `mysql2` package for mysql dialect? Either way, try using another one.

Comment: Was initially trying to use mysql, but Sequelize came up with an error saying I need to use mysql2. So I am currently using mysql2. The strange this is that I can query the DB a few times before this handshake error occurs.

Comment: It's possible that your mysql database has a limit for client connections. Try changing `pool.max` to 3 and check if it works. If it's okay, then you should probably check mysql configuration. If that does not help then I'm out of ideas : )

Comment: Tried with 3, still getting the same error. Tried with 1, 5 and 10 as well.

Comment: May be you can disable SSL or use socket connection?

Comment: SSL is disabled on MySQL. Not setting it on Sequelize.

Answer (score 0):

This turned out to be an issue with the mysql2 package. I had to remove it and use the mysql package instead.

Hopefully this can help someone else out if they come across the same error.

Comment: Any idea what version of the package it was?